# Splitting of short exact sequence of sheaves of vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, exact-sequence

It is well-known that any short exact sequence of vector spaces splits. Is it also true that the short exact sequence of sheaves of $\mathbb C$-vector spaces

$$0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow0$$

always splits? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I do not demand that the vector spaces are finite dimensional. You are right that every $\mathcal{O}_X$-module is in particular a $\mathbb C$-vector space but I am not interested in $\mathcal{O}_X$-splitting. That it too strong.

Comment: Here is a counter example : let $\mathbb{C}$ be the constant sheaf on the circle $X=S^1$ and $i_*\mathbb{C}$ be the skyscraper sheaf supported at a point $x$. Then the surjective map $\mathbb{C}\to i_*\mathbb{C}$ does no split. Indeed, if $s$ is a section, then $$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}i_*\mathbb{C}(X)@>s_X>>\mathbb{C}(X)\\@VVV@VVrV\\i_*(\mathbb{C})(X\setminus\{x\})@>s_{X\setminus\{x\}}>> \mathbb{C}(X\setminus\{x\})\end{CD}$$The maps $s_X$ and $r$ are isomorphisms, but $i_*(\mathbb{C})(X\setminus\{x\})$ is zero. A contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for the counter-example. I accept that. Your counter example actually shows that the statement is false even locally, i.e. there is no open $U$ of $X$ for which the map $\mathbb C|_U\rightarrow i_*\mathbb C|_{U}$ splits. I taught that the statement is correct locally at least.